# web2py and DB transactions

Tags: python, web2py

When exactly the database transaction is being commited? Is it for example at the end of every response generation?

To explain the question: I need to develop a bit more sophisticated application where I have to control DB transactions less or more manually. Especialy I have to be able to design a set of forms with some complex logics behind the forms (some kind of 'wizard') but the database operations must not be commited until the last form and the confirmation.

Of course I could put everything to the session without making any DB change but it's not a solution, the changes are quite complex and realy have to be performed. So the only way is to keep it uncommited.

Now back to the question: if I undertand how is it working in web2py it will be easier for me to decide if thats a good framework for me. I am a java and php programmer, I know python but I don't know web2py yet ...

If you know any web page when it's explained I also wppreciate.

THanks!

Comment: I recommend asking this on the [web2py mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py) -- you'll get more help more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

you can call db.commit() and db.rollback() pretty much everywhere. If you do not and the action does not raise an exception, it commits before returning a response to the client. If it raises an exception and it is not explicitly caught, it rollsback.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the official documentation?  It explains [commit policies](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#commit-and-rollback) and [distributed transactions](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#Distributed-Transaction) pretty well.

Comment: Thanks, I've read it but either I am missing something or it's exactly the opposite I need. I mean - documentation says that everything is commited whenever any action is made (view, controller etc) - and it says that I can commit more often.

Comment: But my question is: how to avoid automatic commit?